There's no Build available in Visual Studio 10 for Python code
I need a custom script to run Shiv and package my python code. I know there are Build > Events that i can use to to run a PreBuild script, but this isn't available for Python, and it looks like the Build doesn't show anything useful either, is there any workaround for this?


Ok, this solution for this was to add these lines to the .pyproj file:
  <Target Name="Build">
     <Exec Command="python3.12 $(ProjectDir)build.py" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ReBuild">
     <Exec Command="python3.12 $(ProjectDir)build.py --rebuild" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CoreCompile" />


you might want to include restore warning suppressor as well:
  <Target Name="_IsProjectRestoreSupported"
          Returns="@(_ValidProjectsForRestore)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_ValidProjectsForRestore Include="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Restore" />


